# Sorting with Perl Eval

Tags: perl, eval

I have a code similar to this:

```
sub mySub{
    my $sortMethod = shift;
    my @arr = @_;

    my @finalArr = eval "$sortMethod @arr";
    foreach( @finalArr ){
         ...do something....
    }
}
```

Then I want to call it like this:

```
mySub( 'reverse', @someArr );
```

or:

```
mySub( 'sort', @someArr );
```

but I get errors:

Number found where operator expected at (eval 2) line 1, near "1 2"
        (Missing operator before  2?)
Number found where operator expected at (eval 2) line 1, near "2 3"
        (Missing operator before  3?)

the array that I'm sending contains numbers from 1 to 5 (as an example)

can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: why do you use eval there?

Comment: because I want to sort that array according to what anybody want's it to be sorted, a specific case might be 'sort mySpecificSort()' and then I print that array, I want to make it dynamic, and not be very specific, just let the guy who calls the method to specify his own sorting method

Answer (score 3):

The error already told you what was wrong

> Number found where operator expected at (eval 2) line 1, near "1 2" (Missing operator before 2?)

It found a number where it expected an operator. The operator would be the comma operator. It told you where it found it, before the number 2.

When you interpolate an array, the elements are joined by whatever is contained in `$"`, which is space by default. So your eval string becomes

```
sort 1 2 3 4
```

Which of course does not work. You need to make it a comma delimited string, which you can do like so:

```
... "$sortmethod " . join(",", @arr);
```

You might be interested in an alternate way to do this:

```
my @reversed = foo(sub { reverse @_ }, @list);
my @sorted   = foo(sub { sort @_ }, @list);

sub foo {
    my $code = shift;
    $code->(@_);
}
```

Another alternate way, which allows you to use strings to lookup a sorting method:

```
my %sort = (
    'numasc'    => \&sort_num_asc,
    'asc'       => \&sort_asc,
    'desc'      => \&sort_desc,
);

my @list = $sort{$method}->(@arr):

sub sort_num_asc {
    sort { $a <=> $b } @_;
}
sub sort_asc {
    sort @_;
}
sub sort_desc {
    sort { $b cmp $a } @_; 
}
```

Comment: even if I specify and array to be @arr=( 3,1,2,5,4) doesn't work

Comment: I was thinking in the alternate way, **+1** for solving the `eval` issue and for the alternate method, that I like more.

Comment: @Birei It's the classic way of passing a code block. It's pretty nice, except for the extra typing, but in a way I like that. I suspect its possible to reduce it to the proper `sort`/`map` style with prototypes, but I never liked to use those.

Comment: @AndreiDoanca [It doesn't work](http://tlp-perl.blogspot.se/2013/06/its-not-working.html) is not a very good way to describe something.

Comment: @AndreiDoanca By which I mean: It should work, it works for me, and it should work for you, so unless you tell me what's wrong, I can't help you.

Comment: what I wanted to say is that using my method, I get the same error when 
    `@arr = ( 3,2,1,5,4);` and when 
    `@arr = join(",", @arr)` I get undef for 
    `@finalArray = eval ( $sortmethod @arr )`

Comment: @AndreiDoanca Yes... `eval` takes an expression or a block, what you have there is two variables following each other, and it doesn't really mean anything. Perhaps you should put back the quoting and see if that works.

Comment: @TLP, thanks, you are right, indeed it work, but for an array containing numbers it work, for an array containing hashes I get `The timeout specified has expired: ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed` from apache, I should mention that I'm doing this in a CGI script and my array contains data from an XML file

Comment: @AndreiDoanca Oh, the horror of even considering using `eval` on tainted data in a CGI application. Why not just hard code the different sorting methods you need? It feels like this is a [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/162416).

Comment: @TLP yes, it does sound like and XY problem, by the way thanks for pointing it out, I never knew about it. Now regarding my solution, the data in the XML comes from scanning some files and put some information in that XML, and displaying it in html. it's not really untained because I know what's in it. the thing is that there are multiple 'categories' in the xml, and I want to view them sorted differently. I want to use the same subroutine for displaying them, and I provide this subroutine the sorting method: for one case it's a simple 'reverse', for another case it a 'sort MyCustomSort...'

Comment: ...continuation.. I wanted to do it dynamically, and not just if(case1){ ... } elsif(case2){} and so on, I felt like doing something else than just hardcoding the cases. Do you have any other suggestion on making it dynamic? if you say that eval is a poor solution

Comment: I've added another suggestion to my answer, where you use a hash to select the appropriate sorting method.

Comment: @TLP thanks for that solution, it's bit better :) now I have to decide if I implement the old if-else or your hash solution. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Did you try escaping Array in your eval string?

I think this should work:

```
my @finalArr;
my $res = eval "\@finalArr = $sortMethod \@arr";
```

Problem here is that you are joining $sortMethod with real value of your @arr. I think you would like to result with something like this:

```
eval "sort @arr";
```

instead of:

```
eval "sort 1,2,3";
```

Comment: Indeed, it does modify the original value of @arr. in my case @arr is coming from an xml file, and I print it in html using CGI, this is the error that comes from apache `Modification of a read-only value attempted at...`

Comment: Try using this lines:
my @finalArr;
my $res = eval "\@finalArr = $sortMethod @arr";

and $res will keep result status of your eval.

Comment: If I do this, I get back where I started, with the same errors `Number found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "3 1" ` this error comes from a test script, and in the real case, apache hangs :|

Comment: @AndreiDoanca The reason you are having these problems is because the `eval` solution is a very poor and fragile solution. If you want it to work and be simpler, use the alternative solution I suggested.

Comment: I agree to not use eval as well. If you still go for quick eval solution then I did typo in my suggestion. Please use:
my @finalArr; my $res = eval "\@finalArr = $sortMethod \@arr"; 

I didn't escape @arr.

Comment: @Sedi, thanks for the input I'll remember this code for future cases